# Chaining JS Set methods results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, set

Why does

```
screens.reduce((acc,s) =>
    acc.add(s._created_by).add(s._last_modified_by), new Set());
```

work as expected (the set gets two things added each iteration), whereas adding `.delete("admin")` as in

```
screens.reduce((acc,s) =>
    acc.add(s._created_by).add(s._last_modified_by).delete("admin"), new Set());
```

results in `TypeError: acc.add is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs for [Set.prototype.delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete):

> Return value
>
> `true` if an element in the Set object has been removed successfully; otherwise `false`

It doesn't return the `Set`. So, if you want to use `reduce` and `delete` like that, you'll have to use two different statements, not just one chained one:

```
screens.reduce((acc,s) => {
  acc
    .add(s._created_by)
    .add(s._last_modified_by)
    .delete("admin");
  return acc;
} , new Set());
```

(I suppose you could also use the comma operator to avoid having to use `{`/`}` blocks, but only for the sake of golfing, it would hurt code clarity)

Comment: OMG - JS still has some way to go to behave like a functional language - thanks!!!!